# Gtk::Widget on_enter_notify when mouse is down?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to have a list of Gtk::Widgets that when clicked on I need to highlight the widget, but when the user holds the button down, and drags to another widget, the first one will 'unhighlight' and the new one will highlight on enter_notify.

I've tried using the on_enter_notify_event, and on_button_press_event in multiple combinations ( yes, I'm adding the events ), but every time I 'press' the widget, it starts a drag event, and enter_notify and leave_notify won't fire.

Is there a way to ignore the drag event? I've tried ending it when it starts, but I think the problem is the on_notify won't trigger with the mouse down. Is there another way of doing it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should handle the highlight by combining the button-down-event/button-release-event.

Comment: @erick2red That's the way I originally had it. The drag event is still started and I cannot highlight other cells.

Comment: Then, take a look at the [GtkButton code] (http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkbutton.c)

Comment: What am I looking for? I've extended Gtk::Layout so I can have a couple labels, and an image, so I don't think the button code really has any affect on what I'm doing. I'm thinking there has to be a way to disable the "begin_drag" event from firing, or a completely different way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently when a widget gets activated or clicked, the GdkDevice 'grab()'s the widget and only sends events to THAT widget. So I've taken the device from the event, and called 'ungrab()' on it so it allows the other cells to receive events. Then on my other cells I check the event->state in the on_enter_notify_event to see if the mouse is down, and voila! The cell is highlighted.

```
bool cell::on_button_press_event(GdkEventButton* event) {
  highlight_cell();

  gdk_device_ungrab(event->device, event->time);

  return true;
}
```